# Java7, BouncyCastle, OSX vs Redhat: "UnrecoverableKeyException"

Tags: java, bouncycastle

At my institution we have a script that has been encrypting and decrypting passwords for about 10 years from a database (please, let's not get into the best-practices of doing that or not; it's a healthy debate in my own community but the business requires it).  It's been doing that running on Java 1.3 using BouncyCastle.

So, essentially, I have a very old keystore with very old passwords, and I need to use those but in an updated codebase running on an upgraded machine with new Java.

We decided to rewrite the codebase surrounding that functionality, which basically requires rewriting this piece as well.  Basically, though, the encryption part of the code is identical.  Now we are deploying it to Java 1.7 on Redhat.  This is where we ran into problems.

My development machine: OSX, Java 1.7 (build 8)

My test machine: Redhat, Java 1.7 (build 9)

The new code executes just fine on my local development machine.
But when I tried to deploy it to our test machine I got "UnrecoverableKeyException: no match".

So on our test machine I tried to deploy it using Java 1.6 -- and lo and behold, that works fine.  I then acquired Java 1.7 build 8 (thinking build 9 was the issue) and tried that, but same error as on build 9.

So it would seem that BouncyCastle:

1. on an OSX machine it will run on Java 1.7
2. on a Redhat machine it won't run on Java 1.7 but does run on Java 1.6 and below.

My question is this: does anyone know if there is in fact a problem with Java 1.7 and BouncyCastle?  I tried looking through the BC website but aside from stating that the latest BC jars are compatible with Java 1.7, the rest of the site seems pretty broken (lot's of 404s).  I tried googling, but almost everything related to this exception is referencing Android and seems unrelated.

Or is there something I'm missing about getting it to run on Java 1.7?  I'm certainly not well-versed in BC, PGP, or anything related to encryption and am mostly winging it to be honest.  LOL

---

More detail:

I am using the bcpg-jdk15on-151.jar which BC states is compatible for JDK 1.5-1.7

By "deploy" I mean I am installing into Apache Karaf 3.

See also: http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Karaf3-BouncyCastle-and-Java7-vs-Java6-td4034721.html

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem (existing public keys could not be used because of a "Wrong key algorithm" error), which was solved by replacing the US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar with the "unlimited strength" versions, which it turns out we had been using previously:  http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html